# java thread not interrupt when running many thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

My project run on java swing there are 2 button (start/stop) for counting.

When I click start button. There is one thread running (Thread-0) ,then click stop button "Thread-0" disappear but when I click start button many times. there are many threads such as Thread-5, Thread-6, .. Thread-10 are running.

**Problem :** 
If click start and then stop counting is ok. but click start many times it's incorrect counting.

**start button**

```
private void btnStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {         
    start();
    btnStart.setEnabled(false);
    btnStop.setEnabled(true);
}
```

**stop button**

```
private void btnStopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {            
    isEnable = false;
    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
    btnStart.setEnabled(true);
}
```

**start() method :**

```
isEnable = true;
Thread refreshPlan = new Thread() {  
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isEnable) {
            try {
                sleep(CYCLE_TIME * 1000);
                PLAN += 1;
                planValue.setText(String.valueOf(PLAN));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //ignore
            }
        }
    };
    };
    refreshPlan.start();
```

Can I run only single thread when click many times in start button ?
any suggestion? thanks.

sorry for my bad english.

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, 
however question about Concurency in Swing is answered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four significant problems here:

- Unless `isEnable` is declared as a volatile variable, there's no guarantee that a write from one thread will be seen in another thread
- Likewise your access to the `PLAN` counter (which is badly named - please follow Java naming conventions) is unsafe. You may wish to consider using `AtomicInteger` for this.
- You're making changes to the UI from your extra thread. You can't do that - in Swing (and most UIs) all access to UI components has to be done on the thread responsible for that UI. See the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.
- Because you only check `isEnabled` one per second, it would be possible to stop and start multiple threads in the meantime... leading to several threads being active at once. This could interfere with your counting.

You might find it's better to use a [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) which fires once a second, and just checks whether or not it's meant to do anything. That way *everything* can be on the UI thread.

Comment: @Phonbopit use  [SwingWorker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15166242/714968), Swing Timer is designated for delaying, manageable endles loop, not for cascading of Workers Threads in Swing

Comment: @mKorbel: What do you mean by "cascading of worker threads"? I was suggesting one endless loop, effectively - every second, it *either* increments the counter or it doesn't, based on the state. I'd rather do that than use extra threads with SwingWorker. Keeping everything on a single thread reduces all kinds of possibilities for error.

Comment: ok, thanks for advise. but I don't get "You're making changes to the UI from your extra thread. You can't do that"

If I use SwingWorker method doInBackground() for calculate PLAN(badly named)  and use method done() for update UI. correct or not?

Comment: @Phonbopit: You could use `SwingWorker`, certainly. But equally you could just do *everything* on the Swing thread, using a timer to fire some code once per second.

Comment: @mKorbel: As I noted in my answer, that could easily be due to the way that any running threads only check once per second. Fundamentally it's a bug which is only present *because* multiple threads are in use. There's no need to have multiple threads when all we need is the state of "we should be counting" or "we shouldn't be counting".

Comment: @Phonbopit noting from doInBackground() is done on EDT without invokeLater, this is reason why there are implemented publish(), process(), method publish should be right method for this job, output is done on EDT

Comment: @Phonbopit, back to your code posted here, any output from Swing Listeners are done on the screen in one moment, in your case nothing happened, GUI freeze untill Thread ended, JButton is disbled and enabled in one moment, or stays disabled in the case that some of event still blocking EDT, usage of Thread.sleep caused described issue

Comment: @Jon Skeet agreed with your comments, but..., simple Swing Timer doesn't fits me for this job, sure is possible

Answer (score -1):

start method is instantiating new Thread() that's why every time u click it, it brings new thread into life.

declare `Thread refreshPlan` class variable then in start method put all the code in this check

```
if(refreshPlan == null || !refreshPlan.isAlive()){
//ur existing code to instantiate new thread.
}
```

Comment: Bad idea - that's got a race condition, as the thread could be alive *just* before you check, but then immediately stop.

Comment: well i don't think there is enough lag there in check nor its time consuming, moreover such edge cases can occur anywhere in conditional flows.

Comment: No, race conditions like this only occur when you don't take account of them. `Thread.isAlive()` should almost *always* be used for diagnostic purposes, not for logic to start another thread.

Comment: but even if thread immediately stops, it shouldn't be a problem, bcz thread did exist at point of check. that means process we want to start is already 'started' or 'still going on'. no matter 1ms or 1s it takes after check or after start(). Isn't it?

Comment: @ay89 question is about issue with EDT