# Understand what is going on with my Prime Numbers Calculation and Prime Numbers JFrame

Tags: java, swing, primes, prime-factoring

I would like to figure out what is going wrong with my code and help understanding what is going on with my Prime Numbers Calculation and Prime Numbers `JFrame`.

1. For some reason, the calculations one was only saying the prime numbers of 1-100 is

   1. I took out the `system.exit(0);` and now I need to click through all the numbers before exiting. What I was hoping to achieve was to get one list that listed all the prime numbers 1-100.
2. Then with the coded prime number calculations, I need to make a Prime Numbers `JFrame`. I have too many errors, which is my first problem and then secondly, because of the errors, I am unable to run the project to see it.

I have posted my code to both, the prime number calculations and my `JFrame`. Any help figuring out what is going on/wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
*********************************************************************************
//Prime Numbers Java Swing JFrame
**********************************************************************************

 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;


 public class ProgrammingAssignment8 extends JFrame 
 implements ActionListener 
 {

//DECLARE BUT DO NOT INSTANTIATE
private JButton calculate;
private JButton clear;
private JButton exit;

//PANELS
private JPanel jpnlMain = new JPanel();

private JPanel jpnlTop = new JPanel();
private JPanel jpnlCenter = new JPanel();
private JPanel jpnlBotton = new JPanel();

private JScrollPane scrollingResult;


//DECLARE JFRAME COMPONENTS
private JLabel jlblName, jlblMaxTest;
private JTextField jtfName, jtfMaxTest;
private JTextArea jtaName, jtaMaxNumbers;
private JButton jbutCalculate, jbutClear, jbutExit;

private CalculateButtonHandler calculateHandler;
private ClearButtonHandler clearHandler;
private ExitButtonHandler exitHandler;





/**
 * @param args
 */

//CLASS CONSTRUCTOR 
public ProgrammingAssignment8 (String sTitle) 
{       

//PREPARE THE JFRAME/WINDOW
    super(sTitle);
//SET TITLE AND SIZE
setTitle(sTitle);
setSize(400,400);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//SET THE LAYOUT
jpnlMain.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,5,5));

 //INSTANTIATE THE JBUTTONS WITH THE PASSED CAPTION AND COLOR AND ADD TO JPANEL
//PUT INTO A METHOD FOR EFFICIENCY AND TO AVOID REPEATING ALL THE CODE
jbtnCalculate = instantiateJButton("Calculate", Color.red);
jbtnClear = instantiateJButton("Clear", Color.blue);
jbtnExit = instantiateJButton("Exit", Color.black);

//INSTANTIATE THE JLABEL COMPONENTS
jlblName = new JLabel ("");

//PREPARE THE CONTAINER
Container ca = getContentPane();
}

set visible(true);


//END CONSTRUCTOR


private JButton instantiateJButton(String, sInCaption, Color inColor)
{
JButton jbtnButton = new JButton(sInCaption);
jbtnButton.setActionCommand(sInCaption);
jbtnButton.addActionListener(this);
jbtnButton.setForeground(inColor);
jbtnButton.setFont(fontChosenFont);
jpnlMain.add(jbutnButton);
return jbtnButton;

//END INSTANTIATE JBUTTON

//CLASS EVENT HANDLER   
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)

{
    //FIND OUT WHICH BUTTON WAS PRESSED BY USING THE ACTION COMMAND VALUE
    String sActionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

    //FROM THE ACTIONEVENT OBJECT, GET AN INSTANCE OF THE JBUTTON THAT WAS PRESSED
    JButton jbtnSource = (JButton) e.getSource();

    jbtnSource.setEnabled(false);

    //LET THE USER KNOW WHAT BUTTON WAS CLICKED
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "You pressed the "" sActionCommand + " button", this.getTitle(), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}

//END ACTIONPERFORMED (java.awt.event.ActionEvent e)

//EXECUTION STARTING POINT

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ProgrammingAssignment8 = new ProgrammingAssignment8("Instantiates with a Method");

}
//END main(String[] args)


}
//END ProgrammingAssignment8 CLASS


***********************************************************************************
PRIME NUMBERS CALCULATIONS
***********************************************************************************

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class ProgrammingAssignment7 
{

/**
 * @param args
 * @return 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //Scanner Scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //DECLARE VARIABLES
    int x = 1;
    int i = 1;
    int iNumber = 1;
    boolean bNotPrime = false;
    boolean bIsPrime = true;
    int iNumberToTest;
    int iPrimeCheck;
    int iCounter;
    int iResult = 1;
    int iFact = 1;
    int iLimit = 100;
    String OutputStr = null;





    System.out.println("Prime numbers between 1 and " + iLimit);

    //loop through the numbers one by one
    for(i=1; i < 100; i++)
    {

            bIsPrime = true;

            //check to see if the number is prime
            for(int j = 2; j < i ; j++){

                    if(i % j == 0){
                            bIsPrime = false;
                            break;
                    }
            }
            // print the number
            if(bIsPrime)

                OutputStr = "The Prime Numbers of 1 - 100 are: " + i + "\n";

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, OutputStr, "PRIME NUMBERS", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                   //System.out.print(i + "\n" );






    //LISTS NUMBERS 1 THROUGH 100, INITIALIZE INTEGER NAMED I, IF IT IS LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO 100 THEN ADD ONE TO THE LOOP



    /* for (int i=1; i<=100; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }



    /* iNumber = 7;

    for (iNumber = 1; iNumber <= 100; iNumber++)
        iResult = iNumber / 1;
    System.out.println(iResult);

    /* for ( iNumber = 2; iNumber <= 100; iNumber++ )
    {
      if ( iNumber % iNumber == 0 )
      {
        bIsPrime = false;
    break;

      }
    }

    return bIsPrime;
}

*/





    /* iNumber = 1; 
    while (iNumber < 100) iNumber++; 
    { 
        System.out.print(iNumber + " ");
        System.out.println();


        for (iNumber = iNumber - 1; iNumber > 2; iNumber++) 
        { //divides the number by each number less than the number itself and also greater than 1 (because 1 is a factor of every number, and every number is a factor of itself)
            if (iNumber % iNumber != 0) 
                System.out.println(iNumber + " is a prime number.");




            { //else if the number is evenly divisible by a number other than itself and 1 (we weeded out those cases in the above for statement), then it sets the boolean to be true, and breaks the for loop
                bNotPrime = false;
                iNumber = 1;
            }

        }

        if (bIsPrime = true) 
        { //if the number is not not a prime, then it prints the number and the for loop moves on 

        }

        else if (bNotPrime = false)
        { //otherwise the for loop moves on
            System.out.println(iNumber + " is not a prime number.");

            */              


}
}
}
```

Comment: You start checking for primes starting from j=2, this automatically puts IsPrime true for i = 1.

Comment: *"because of the errors, I am unable to run the project to see it."*  Fix that 1st, then see the advice of @NPE for run-time.  This seems 'overly broad'.  BTW - get it working in the command line with Scanner first, to check the logic.  Then figure how to transform it to a GUI.

Comment: [..........](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15166242/714968)

Comment: Usually, when I fix "the right thing" all the errors go away. This time, I am unsure of what to fix. I am using the debugger right now to try, as well. I was hoping that someone might be able to look at the work I have done and guide me as to what is causing the problem and what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5):

- `set visible(true);` is out side the constructor and is not a valid method name, it should be `setVisible(true);`, move up so that it appears just before the `}` that is currently above it...
- `private JButton instantiateJButton(String, sInCaption, Color inColor)` is not a valid method signature, you've added a `,` after `String` where it doesn't need to be, it should be `private JButton instantiateJButton(String sInCaption, Color inColor)`
- `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "You pressed the "" sActionCommand + " button", this.getTitle(), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);` is missing a `+` and has too many `"`.  I think it should be `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "You pressed the " + sActionCommand + " button", this.getTitle(), JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);`
- `ProgrammingAssignment8 = new ProgrammingAssignment8("Instantiates with a Method");` is not a valid assignment, you're not actually assigning the value to anything...something like `ProgrammingAssignment8 assignment = new ProgrammingAssignment8("Instantiates with a Method");` will fix it.

The following is not a valid comment...

```
***********************************************************************************
PRIME NUMBERS CALCULATIONS
***********************************************************************************
```

This is...

```
/***********************************************************************************
PRIME NUMBERS CALCULATIONS
***********************************************************************************/
```

- I have no defintions for `CalculateButtonHandler`, `ClearButtonHandler`, `ExitButtonHandler`, `jbtnCalculate`, `jbtnClear`, `jbtnExit` or `fontChosenFont` so I can't comment, needless to say, it won't work until they're written...

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is store the prime numbers in a collection. Look at for example ArrayList. It's like an array, but grows dynamically so that you don't have to specify the size in advance.

One you have the list you can show that list to the user.

Comment: *"Look at for example ArrayList"*  Or go for a Generic `List` instead and use whatever expandable container best suits.  In this particular case of 'list in (Swing) GUI' it is perhaps odd that `Vector` is preferable because `JList` (for example) has constructors that accept a `Vector`. ;) +1 for the advice in general.